# Digital-Metaphors Report Builder string field size cache

Tags: delphi, reportbuilder

I was wondering if anyone has a solution to this.

Lets say we have a varchar(10) field in a database table and this is included in hundreds of Report Builder reports.

Now if we increase the size of this field to now be a varchar(20) we have the problem where all data longer than 10 charaters will be truncated in the reports unless each report is physically edited by opening the data tab, removing the filed and reselecting it. Alternatively it can be done by opening the rtm file in a text editor and searching for the field.

Note that I am not talking about the physical display size of a field but the data field size.

Is there another way to make report builder reports somehow "refresh" the field sizes from the datasource?

thanks
Darren